# Intentionally fail an angular promise if some conditions are met?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

If I have some chained Angular promises like this:

```
promiseB = promiseA.then(function(result) {

    if (result==0) {
        // result is not allowed to be zero - this is an error
        // Do something here to make this promise fail ?!?!?
    }
    return result + 1;
});
```

I'd like to modify the code so that under some cases the promise fails, let's say that if this 'then' function gets result==0 then I consider that to be an error scenario. I actually want this to error.

What can I do to in order to make this promise fail, is raising an exception enough or do I need to signal failure in a more specific kind of way?

Comment: Have you looked at the defer() method? That gives you much more control over the outcome using resolve()/reject()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject `$q` service, and call `$q.reject()`. [Read The Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

```
promiseB = promiseA.then(function(result) {
    if (result==0) {
        return $q.reject(result);
    }
    return result + 1;
});
```

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var myPromise = $q(function(resolve, reject) {
      $http.get('http://someurl').then(function(data){
        reject('some reason');
        //if the result is not 0 return resolve(data)
      });
  });
  myPromise.catch(function(err){
        console.log('err',err);
  })
```

take a look at https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns as well

Answer (score -2):

from the Promise API section in this page: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

This method returns a new promise which is resolved or rejected via the return value of the successCallback, errorCallback (unless that value is a promise, in which case it is resolved with the value which is resolved in that promise using promise chaining). It also notifies via the return value of the notifyCallback method. The promise cannot be resolved or rejected from the notifyCallback method.

so it seems basically you just need to return false in your callback function, i.e.

```
promiseB = promiseA.then(function(result) {
    if (result==0) {
        return false;
    }
    // Indeed I don't understand how this result + 1 is gonna be used...
    return result + 1;
});
```